# I want an other table to be updated when I create an entry

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want `start_date` and `start_time` copied into `latest_time` and `latest_date`,
 while adding a new entry into my `logbook`. 
 But I want dependency on `logbook.logbook_index_id = logbook_index.id` for all entries too.

```
mysql> describe logbook;
+-------------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                         | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                            | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| logbook_index_id              | int(10) unsigned      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date                    | date                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time                    | time                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |


mysql> describe logbook_index;
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_date         | date                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_time         | time                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latest_date        | date                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latest_time        | time                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

atm I got this far ...

```
create trigger update_dates after insert on logbook
for each row update logbook_index
set latest_date = start_date where logbook_index.id = logbook_index_id;
```

I do it mostly wrong I bet. How does this work correctly and how do I get the time copied too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly: 
For this I would suggest using a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

You can put an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the table that you insert, inside the trigger you can put the update to the other table.

In order to access variables from the newly insert record, you need to do the following:

```
UPDATE logbook_index 
SET latest_date = NEW.start_date 
WHERE logbook_index.id = NEW.logbook_index_id;
```

Notice the keyword `NEW` that is used to access the newly insert record.

If you were using an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, you could access the old values by using `OLD`

Comment: I tried what you said, but now I have a new problem. Post is updated.

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is a [Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html), a procedure that's automatically invoked in response to an event, in your case the insertion of a row in the `logbook` table.

Comment: I tried what you said, but now I have a new problem. Post is updated.